# Asynchronous, Multiple HTTP requests in a While Loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine

The code below is intended to send *multiple* HTTP requests *asynchronously* in a *while loop*, and depending on the response from each request(request "X" always returns "XXX", "Y" always returns "YYY" and so on), do something and *sleep* for `interval` seconds specified for each request.

---

However, it throws an error...

```
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
```

Could anyone help me how I could fix the code to realise the intended behaviour?

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def run_forever(self, coro, interval):
        while True:
            res = await coro
            await self._onresponse(res, interval)

    async def _onresponse(self, res, interval):
        if res == "XXX":
            # ... do something with the resonse ...
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
        if res == "YYY":
            # ... do something with the resonse ...
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
        if res == "ZZZ":
            # ... do something with the resonse ...
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)


async def request(something):
    # ... HTTP request using aiohttp library ...
    return response


async def main():
    c = Client()
    await c.run_forever(request("X"), interval=1)
    await c.run_forever(request("Y"), interval=2)
    await c.run_forever(request("Z"), interval=3)
    # ... and more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you can't await a coroutine more than once. Instead of passing a coroutine into `run_forever` and then awaiting it in a loop, passing the coroutine's argument(s) instead and await a new coroutine each iteration of the loop.

```
class Client:
    async def run_forever(self, value, interval):
        while True:
            res = await rqequest(value)
            await self._response(response, interval)
```

You also need to change how you await `run_forever`. `await` is blocking, so when you await something with an infinite loop, you'll never reach the next line. Instead, you want to gather multiple coroutines as once.

```
async def main():
    c = Client()
    await asyncio.gather(
        c.run_forever("X", interval=1),
        c.run_forever("Y", interval=2),
        c.run_forever("Z", interval=3),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why we are not allowed to await  a coroutine multiple times?

Comment: A coroutine will always run only once. In languages that allow multiple awaits your code will still not work since request will be called only thrice.